# How do I list users with roles that have administrator privileges in an embed for serverinfo

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

**Purpose:**
I want the server info command in my bot to mention all users who have a role that has administrator not the roles but the people who possess the role which has administrator, so like a list of people who have the role that has admin.

**More Insight:**

so the bot checks how many roles are there in the server and what roles have admin=True then it lists the users who have those roles. SO they'd be considered an admin in my ".serverinfo" command.

**My code:**

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['sinfo'])
async def serverinfo(ctx, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    
    admin_roles = [role for role in ctx.guild.roles if role.permissions.administrator]
    members = set([member.display_name for role in admin_roles for member in role.members])

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Server Information {ctx.guild.name}' , description= 'Server Info' , color=0x8FE381, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url =f'{ctx.guild.icon_url}')
    embed.add_field(name= "Owner" , value= f"{ctx.guild.owner}")
    embed.add_field(name= "Admins" , value= f" " .join(members.mention))   #my attempt
    embed.add_field(name= "Region" , value= f"{ctx.guild.region}")
    embed.add_field(name= "Members" , value= f"{ctx.guild.member_count}")
    embed.add_field(name= "Server Roles" , value= f"{len(ctx.guild.roles)}")
    embed.add_field(name= "Text Channels" , value= f"{len(ctx.guild.text_channels)}")
    embed.add_field(name= "Voice Channels" , value= f"{len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)}")
    embed.add_field(name= "Server Boosts" , value= f"{ctx.guild.premium_subscription_count}")
    embed.add_field(name= "Credit to" , value= f"ャ  | MysT#9105")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}" , icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Sorry, I'm new to python I could not figure out how to do that with no knowledge of how python works that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `role.members`, but make sure you have `intents.members` enabled. Here's an example

```py
# Getting the role
role = ctx.guild.get_role(id_here)
# Going through every member and pinging him
for member in role.members:
    await ctx.send(member.mention)
```

Also the `guild` argument is useless there, you already have it in `ctx.guild`.

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role%20members#discord.Role.members)

EDIT:

```py
# Getting the roles that have administrator set to True
admin_roles = [role for role in ctx.guild.roles if role.permissions.administrator]

for role in admin_roles:
    for member in roles:
        await ctx.send(member)
```

Comment: But it does not check if the said member has admin?

Comment: so the bot checks how many roles are there in the server and what roles have admin=True then it lists the users who have those roles. SO they'd be considered an admin in my ".serverinfo" command.

Comment: No, you have to hardcode the ID of the role. I'll edit my answer

Comment: One last thing if you mind showing me how to embed that? like listing them.